# I can't import pandas in pycharm there is a error: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

I can't import pandas in pycharm as it says:AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'

my python version is python 3.6 
my OS is win10
here is my whole imformantion about the error：

```
import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\api.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas.io.packers import read_msgpack, to_msgpack
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\packers.py", line 65, in <module>
    import pandas.core.internals as internals
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error when I updated my Python version from 3.5 to 3.6. In python 3.5, I was using pandas 0.19.2, so I updated the panda's version to 0.20.1 and the importation was successful.